# Regex scrape of the same form_id name but different values

Tags: html, regex, xpath

I would like to know using either regex or xpath how can you scrape a form id value from a html page that has the same form_id names example below, I would to scrape the value from the 2nd form_id name any advice for the best way to achieve this using only regex or xpath? Thanks

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form" />
```

I would like to scrape the value from this form_id below: "webform_client_form_"

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="webform_client_form_" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Targeting second input with XPath:

```
(//input[@name='form_id']/@value)[2]
```

Using utilities that work on DOM structure is the preferable choice here.

Comment: (//input[@name='form_id']/@value)[2]  Works perfect!!! Thank  you very much!!! @revo

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it works using check mark beside of it or up-vote it if it was helpful.